# Replace last line of XML file

Tags: bash, shell

Looking for help creating a script that will replace the last line of an XML file with a tag. I have a few hundred files so I'm looking for something that will process them in a loop. I've managed to rename the files sequentially like this:

```
posts1.xml
posts2.xml
posts3.xml
```

etc...

to make it easier to loop through. But I have no idea how to write a script to do this. I'm open to using either Linux or Windows (but i would guess that Linux is better for this kind of task).

Comment: Can you post an example of your input and what you want to change it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you want to append a line to every file:

```
sed -i '$a<YOUR_SHINY_NEW_TAG>' *xml
```

To replace the last line:

```
sed -i '$s/.*/<YOUR_SHINY_NEW_TAG>/' *xml
```

***But do note***, `sed` is not the ideal tool to modify xml.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because I used the append option in the end after first using `sed -ie '$d' posts*.xml` to remove the last line

Answer (score 3):

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net) is a command-line toolkit for performing XML parsing and manipulations. Note that as an XML-aware toolkit, it'll respect XML structure, character encoding and entity substitution.

Check out the [ed](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html) command to see how to modify documents. You can wrap this in a standard bash loop.

e.g. in a doc consisting of a chain of `<elem>`s, you can add a following `<added>5</added>`:

```
mkdir new
for x in *.xml; do
    xmlstarlet ed -a "//elem[count(//elem)]" -t elem -n added -v 5 $x > new/$x
done
```

Comment: Brian, thank you for this answer, I was not aware of this toolkit. I actually went with the sed approach in the end because I just wanted to do a simple replace with the same closing tag for each file. But I think this toolkit will come in handy in the future

Answer (score 2):

Linux way using `sed`:

To edit the last line of the file in place, you can use `sed`:

```
sed -i '$s_pattern_replacement_' filename
```

To change the whole line to "replacement" use `$s_.*_replacement_`. Be sure to escape any `_`'s in `replacement` with a `\`.

To loop over files, just use `for`:

```
for f in /path/posts*.xml; do sed -i '$s_.*_replacement_' $f; done
```

This, however, is a dirty way as it's not aware of the XML structure, whereas the XML structure is not affected by newlines. You have to be sure the last line of the files contains exactly what you expect it to.

Comment: Or aware of encodings or entities. I wouldn't say it won't work, but it's a limited subset

Comment: Lev, I got an error when I used this command : `Unknown option to 's'`
I think there may be some special characters in the file that is causing this.

Comment: `sed -i '$s/.*/</posts>/' *.xml`
`sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to ``s'`

Comment: @johnmcp My bad. See, this is because `/` is a delimiter for `s` command, but there's also a `/` in the replacement. I thought of this when starting to write the answer, so I used another delimiter: `_`. But then I forgot and used `/` again.. I'll clean up the answer, and you have two options: use `_` as delimiter or escape `/` in the tag: `<\/posts>`.

Comment: Ah of course, I should have spotted that as well. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It makes little to no difference whether you're on Linux, Windows or MacOS

The question is what language do you want to use?

The following is an example in c# (not optimized, but read it as speudocode):

```
string rootDirectory = @"c:\myfiles";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(rootDirectory, "*.xml");

foreach (var file in files)
{
  var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
  lines[lines.Length - 1] = "whatever you want here";
  File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
}
```

You can compile this and run it on Windows, Linux, etc..

Or you could do the same in Python.

Of course this method does not actually parse the XML,
but you just wanted to replace the last line right?

Comment: He just wants to replace the last line, whilst likely respecting XML character encodings, entity encodings and structure etc. I think you're skipping a *major* part of the required solution.

Comment: Yep, your solution nailed it Brian :-) Just found the question a bit vague and I wanted to point out the OS is not really a factor here :) He should mark yours as the answer though :)